# TreeView won't populate

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I got a tree view what won't populate,
when I add Nodes they don't show up in the UI but they are in the object,
and when I set in Visual Studio the nodes they show up,

I tried everything

```
TreeView.Refresh();
TreeView.BeginUpdate();
TreeView.Focus();
```

Im annoyed by it, I worked many times with the TreeView but this never happend?

UPDATE:

I add Nodes with this code:

```
PathSelectTree.Nodes.Add("hello?");
```

UPDATE 2:

When I add the nodes before

```
InitializeComponent();
```

it works...

UPDATE 3:

the add node is in the form load event but I also tried a button click event

Comment: how do you add nodes ? please provide the code

Comment: @Tigran Like this: PathSelectTree.Nodes.Add("hello?");

Comment: I don't mean to come off as condescending but, you say that you've worked many times with the TreeView and things have worked fine. What has changed or what is different from the times that it has worked?

Comment: Just a thought: Turn off any ajax you might have that isn't configured correctly to update your control.  Might want to show more of the markup code or page life cycle code.

Comment: You're going to have to show more code, especially the code that is actually adding nodes.  It sounds like you're adding it in the constructor, and it should be after `InitializeComponent`, so please show that entire method to us.

Comment: @Yetti the only change is that I use C# now instead of VB.net

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses: you'll need to show the entire user code and the designer code (perhaps simplified a little) to allow anyone to help. Actually, when you do PathSelectTree.Nodes.Add("hello?") before InitializeComponent(), that call should throw an exception in a normal setup, as the fields containing control references are null before InitializeComponent()...

Comment: @Alan I like to show it but I can't get the code atm since Im not allowed to go on my laptop -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, guys Im sorry for wasting your time,

I had a

```
InitializeComponent
```

in my constructor and in my formload event,

Im really sorry,

Answer (score 1):

Check for a `Treeview.BeginUpdate` inside the `Initializecomponent` without an EndUpdate.

Try also calling `TreeView.EndUpdate()`, just to be sure.

Comment: How about the DrawMode property. If it is changed in the initialize component to OwnerDrawAll, it could be that the normal drawing of the nodes is never executed